# Como importar todos los datos de un .csv a una tabla en MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Al crear un schema y a continuacion una tabla, en MySql Workbench, pincho con el boton derecho en la tabla y le doy a table data import wizard y seleciono un archivo .csv que tiene 250 filas y 5 columnas separadas por coma ( , ) pero a la hora de hacer la consulta SELECT * FROM bbdd.tabla; me salen solo 92 filas.

Alguien sabe como solucionar esto?

Comment: fijate en el log si hubo algún error o warning

Comment: 16:21:54 SELECT * FROM bbdd.paradas LIMIT 0, 5000 91 row(s) returned 0.000 sec / 0.000 sec

No me da ningun error

Comment: fijate si en el import da alguna razón por la cual entran 91 y no 250 ( algun campo que esté como key y no inserta pq está duplicada por ejemplo )

Comment: puede ser, prueba ponerle  de tipo REAL o DOUBLE como para mantenerlos como números ( depende de para qué se utilicen luego, podes insertarlos como texto y procesarlos después )

Comment: otra opción es ver cuales registros no entraron y deducir de ahí el por qué

Comment: Si que acabo de ver un error:
 - Row import failed with error: ("Out of range value for column '@id' at row 1", 1264)

Pero en vez de int le he puesto bigint y los otros con double ya esta arreglado Gracias.